# How make the Button disabled in Angular form

Tags: angular

I have a button that I need to disable when the form is empty so when I open the form at the beginning it should be disabled and make it enable when any inputs in form get value, I have this code, but it is not disable when form loads, as when form load it is valid, how I can make it not valid so the button will be disabled?

HTML:

```
<button
  class="search-form__btn"
  type="submit"
  size="large"
  [disabled]="!isEnabled"
>
  Run Search
</button>
```

TS file:

```
public get isEnabled(): boolean {
  const form: FormGroup = this.searchForm;
  if (form.get('filters.firstName').value !== ''
    || form.get('filters.lastName').value !== ''
    || form.get('filters.company').value !== ''
    || form.get('filters.phone').value !== ''
    || form.get('filters.email').value !== ''
    || form.get('filters.officer').value !== ''
    || form.get('filters.number').value !== ''
    || form.get('filters.state').value !== '') {
    return form.valid;
  }
}
```

and this is my form:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
    filters: this.fb.group({
      searchString: [""],
      firstName: [""],
      lastName: [""],
      company: [""],
      email: [null, [Validators.email]],
      phone: [""],
      officer: [""],
      number: [""],
      state: [""],
      exactMatch: [false],
    }),
    pageSize: [100],
    currentPage: [1],
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add Validators.required for fields and bind disabled attr like so:

```
<button 
  class="search-form__btn"
  type="submit"
  size="large"
  [disabled]="searchForm.invalid">Run Search</button>
```

Comment: I added this and still it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
[disabled]="searchForm.invalid"
```

Comment: Please try to elaborate and explain the solution